# Issue in Angular PATCH statement

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am new to Angular and using version 9. In the code i use the below patch. Server side entity I try to update is a "Building". I want to just update the "FloorComment" attribute of the entity.

```
updateFloorComment() {
    if (this.floorComment) {
      var patchDocument = [{ "op": "replace", "path": "/FloorComment", "value": this.floorComment }]

      this.subs.add(this.buildingFloorService
        .updateFloorComment(this.building.reportId, this.building.id, patchDocument)
        .subscribe());
    }
  }
```

in the code line `.updateFloorComment(this.building.reportId, this.building.id, patchDocument)` i get an error saying:

> Argument of type '{ op: string; path: string; value: string; }[]' is
> not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

**Updated**

In the service the method is:

```
  updateFloorComment(reportId, buildingId, FloorComment: string): Observable<any> {
    return this._httpService.patch(`${this.reportsApi}/${reportId}/buildings/${buildingId}/floors/floor-comment`, FloorComment, httpOptions);
  }
```

But their seem to be an error under HttpOptions as "Expected 2 arguments, but got 3"

Would really appreciate some help on this

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example. This likely doesnt have anything to do with the PATCH method of an http service call. We need to see the `buildingFloorService.updateFloorComment` to help you. Looks like the arguments you provided don't match the method signature for that method.

Comment: @zero01alpha updated the service method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue. I have not properly passed the parameters in the service method. I updated the code in the service method.

```
  updateFloorComment(reportId: string, buildingId: string, payload: any): Observable<any> {
    return this._httpService.patch<Building>(`${this.reportsApi}/${reportId}/buildings/${buildingId}/floors/floor-comment`, payload);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what parameter types you are using in buildingFloorService.updateFloorComment() but it seems like you are trying to assign a non-string type to a string variable. I am guessing it could be the patchDocument var in the service method.

Comment: i have updated the code which invokes the service call.